# Ubuntu 20.04 Kernel driver not installed (rc=-1908)

Tags: kernel, virtualbox, virtualization

I use Virtualbox and yesterday it display me this error Kernel

> driver not installed (rc=-1908)
>
> The VirtualBox Linux kernel driver is either not loaded or not set up
> correctly. Please reinstall virtualbox-dkms package and load the
> kernel module by executing
>
> 'modprobe vboxdrv'
>
> as root.
>
> If your system has EFI Secure Boot enabled you may also need to sign
> the kernel modules (vboxdrv, vboxnetflt, vboxnetadp, vboxpci) before
> you can load them. Please see your Linux system's documentation for
> more information.
>
> where: suplibOsInit what: 3 VERR_VM_DRIVER_NOT_INSTALLED (-1908) - The
> support driver is not installed. On linux, open returned ENOENT.
> I found a lot of tips and tutorials but nothing wworks. I'm using Ubuntu 20.04

Comment: You need to install VB 6.1.16 for the 5.8 kernel.

Comment: Debian upstream will be updated soon (hopefully) so users will be able to just update (which is automatic in 20.04).